# VSCode - Refresh Local Debugging HTML Changes Do Not Show if Subfolder

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0

I have a NET Core solution folder that has 2 sub-folders in VS Code on a Mac.

```
MVCSolution (top folder)
+--- MVCApp (subfolder)
+--- MVCApp.Tests (subfolder)
```

MVCApp is just a vanilla MVC app, pretty much out of the box template.  MVCApp.Tests are a few Unit Tests.  All work just fine.

My .vscode and /Properties folders are located in the MVCSolution root.

The .vscode config json files all have references to the subfolder.  For example, in launch.json:

```
...
"sourceFileMap": {
  "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/MVCApp/Views"
}
...
```

Everything working hunky-dory with 1 exception.  During a local debug session (Chrome browser), if I make a change to the HTML of one of my razor pages (eg. Home/Index change the h1 tag from 'Home' -> 'Home2'), and refresh the page in Chrome, it doesn't change.  If I stop the debugging session and relaunch again, it will change then.  It's kind of annoying, especially when I'm just tweaking client look&feel stuff.

I'm sure I've got a config wrong or missing some setting somewhere.

If I use VS Code and open just the MVCApp folder and add the .vscode configs and Properties back in to the MVCApp folder with correct paths, all works fine.  Changes are reflected on browser refresh.

Any ideas of how to fix?

** ** EDIT ** **

For those looking for sample code, here's how you can replicate.  Open up VSCode and go into the terminal.  Start by making a solution directory and type in the following commands to create a sample solution with 2 projects.

```
mkdir TestMVC

dotnet new mvc -n TestMVCApp

dotnet new xunit -n TestMVCApp.Tests
```

Then, open the folder TestMVC in VS Code.  You'll need to add the launch.json and tasks.json files to .vscode folder

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp/bin/Debug/net6.0/TestMVCApp.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp/Views"
            },
            "logging": {
                "moduleLoad": false,
                "engineLogging": false,
                "exceptions": true,
                "programOutput": true,
                "browserStdOut": false            
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp/TestMVCApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "watch",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "watch",
                "run",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp/TestMVCApp.csproj",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "clean",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "clean",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp/",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "label": "publish-release",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [
                "publish",
                "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp/",
                "--configuration",
                "Release",
                "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
                "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile",
            "dependsOn": "clean"
        }
    ]
}
```

Launch a Debugging session in VS Code and you should see the default home page.  Try to change the H1 tag from 'Welcome' to 'Hello' in your Views/Home/Index page and refresh to see if the changes are applied.  It will only get applied if you stop the debugger and re-launch another debugging session.

** ** EDIT 2 ** **

Per Chen's suggestion, here's what my Program.cs looks like AFTER adding the AddRazorRuntimeCompilation line:

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();



//NOTE: Error Occurs Here - type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Linq.dll: 'Value cannot be null.' 

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Just standard VS Code/.NET installation using .NET Core Launch (web) from launch.json

Comment: it would be nice if you provided the launch.json for a [mre].

Comment: What does your `launch.json` look like? How to run the program? I use `dotnet watch run` to test, but there is no problem.

Comment: Adding code so you can reproduce this issue on your machine.  Again, I'm using a Mac (M1 MB Pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `launch.json` you provided for testing, and it did exactly what you said. I installed and registered [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/8.0.0-preview.3.23177.8) after changing the `cwd`, and the changed content will be applied after the page is refreshed. You can have a try:

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            //...
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/TestMVCApp",
        },
        //...
    ]
}
```

Then install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet Package:

```
dotnet add TestMVCApp package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
```

And in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and can't seem to get it to work.  I added the NuGet package, changed the launch.json 'cwd' line, and modified the Program.cs to include AddRazorRuntimeCompilation.  However, now I get an error when launching when it its the app.MapControllerRoute line in Program.cs.  I'm adding my program.cs to my original post.

Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ArgumentNullException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Linq.dll: 'Value cannot be null.'

Comment: I figured it out.  Instead of using 'builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();', I used     'builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();' in Program.cs and it worked